# What does /nodetect flag do, when using the tf status?

Tags: tfs, version-control, tfvc, tf-cli

When interacting with TFS from the command line, the `tf status` command has an [undocumented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/status-command#parameters) flag named `/nodetect`. What is it for? What does it do?

My best guess is that it prevents it from trying to be smart about detecting changed files, but I can't seem to verify any change in behaviour when running the command with that flag.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with powershell.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT: It is in the sense that it confirmed what I was thinking it did. I haven't accepted it as the right answer because, to me, there is no evidence that actually indicates that is truly what it does. Do you have the pull to update this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/status-command ?

Comment: I've provided a feedback at website below: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/292.

Answer (score 0):

It only looks at files that have been explicitly check out or have been registered as a pending change. It won't look at the stored hashes to detect changed or missing or added files. It's useful for local workspaces, in server workspaces it doesn't add any behavior, as with server workspaces you need to always be explicit about your changes through the checkout/add/move commands.

Comment: it also checks files with Change type "add" and "delete", not only "edit"

Comment: @AlexanderIvasyuk of course. It checks in every file with an explicit pending change.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the feedback at website below:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/292

> Steve has mentioned "I've added this to our documentation backlog and
>   we'll get it updated."